# yml table materialization in snowflake not working

Tags: dbt

I am working through the fundamentals course. In the models section of the yml, I have specified the +materialized: table instruction, yet the dim_customers is still created as a view in snowflake.

But if I put in the config block atop the sql block, it works fine.

Might you have any tips?

#### yml

```
name: 'jaffle_shop'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'default'

model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"

models:
  jaffle:
    marts:
      core:
        +materialized: table
    staging:
      +materialized: view
```

#### project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the name of your project into the `models:` config in your dbt_project.yml:

```yaml
models:
  jaffle_shop:
    jaffle:
      marts:
        core:
          +materialized: table
      staging:
        +materialized: view
```

Comment: Hi Josh. thanks for the answer. I had only provided an excerpt. I edited and added the full version. I did have the name defined.

Comment: @JimMurphy I have updated my answer.  You need to have the project name, then the path (inside models), and then the configuration.

Comment: That did it. Thank you, @Josh. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[file-tree & yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPkVi.png)
[snowflake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVaBt.png)

Hi, I am facing a similar issue, even though the project name is added.
I also tried adding/removing the +enabled option.

Overriding with config macro works.